# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value Error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a dynamic SQL query and perform insert operation. But for some reason, I am getting
error: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '`

Please can anyone help me in resolving this error. Getting error at `values('@file_type_id'`

Below is my SQL code:

```
    DECLARE @file_name VARCHAR(100) = 'MyFile'
    DECLARE @file_type_id INT = 1
    DEclare @filing_id bigint = 57
    DECLARE @created_at DATETIME = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @created_by BIGINT = 2
    DECLARE @is_confidential bit = 1

    set @insertquery = 
    '
    DECLARE @Document AS VARBINARY(MAX)
    SELECT @Document = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM OPENROWSET( BULK ''C:\SampleTestFiles\MyWordDoc.doc'', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS Doc

    Insert  ['+@databasename+'].['+@schemaname+'].['+@tablename+'] 
          ( [file_type_id], [file],  [file_name], [filing_id], [created_at], [created_by], [is_confidential])
   values ( '@file_type_id', @Document, @file_name, @filing_id , @created_at, @created_by, @is_confidential)
   '
    exec (@insertquery)
```

Comment: `'['+@databasename+']` isn't injection safe! Use [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Also, `'values ( '@file_type_id', ...` isn't correct. you should be **parametrising** the value of `@file_type_id`

Comment: Because you are building up a string which contains all the string literals, not the values of your variables. You can pass parameters to dynamic sql but you need to use sp_executesql.

Comment: but mainly you are not concatenating  '@file_type_id' - try ' + @file_type_id + '

Comment: After doing ' + @file_type_id + ' it is still giving same error

Comment: `@file_type_id` is an `int` so the rest of your statment will be implicitly cast to an `nvarchar(MAX)`, but `' + @file_type_id + '` is also not the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *suspect* this is what you are after. Note that I have **parametrised** the variables, and *safely* quoted the values of your dynamic objects:

```
DECLARE @databasename sysname,
        @schemaname sysname,
        @tablename sysname;

DECLARE @file_name varchar(100) = 'MyFile',
        @file_type_id int = 1,
        @filing_id bigint = 57,
        @created_at datetime = GETDATE(),
        @created_by bigint = 2,
        @is_confidential bit = 1,
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
        @insertquery nvarchar(MAX);

SET @insertquery = N'DECLARE @Document AS VARBINARY(MAX);' + @CRLF +
                   N'SELECT @Document = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM OPENROWSET( BULK ''C:\SampleTestFiles\MyWordDoc.doc'', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS Doc;' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                   N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@databasename) + '.' +  QUOTENAME(@schemaname) + N'.' +  QUOTENAME(@tablename) + N'  ( [file_type_id], [file],  [file_name], [filing_id], [created_at], [created_by], [is_confidential])' + @CRLF + 
                   N'VALUES (@file_type_id, @Document, @file_name, @filing_id , @created_at, @created_by, @is_confidential);';

--PRINT @insertquery; --Your best friend.

EXEC sp_executesql @insertquery, N'@file_name varchar(100),@file_type_id int,@filing_id bigint,@created_at datetime, @created_by bigint,@is_confidential bit', @file_name, @file_type_id, @filing_id, @created_at, @created_by, @is_confidential;
```

I can't test the above, however, if you get any errors I would suggest looking at your best friend. if, however, I use the declarations below...:

```
DECLARE @databasename sysname = N'MyDB',
        @schemaname sysname = N'dbo',
        @tablename sysname = N'MyTable';
```

I get this statement, which appears to be correct:

```
DECLARE @Document AS VARBINARY(MAX);
SELECT @Document = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:\SampleTestFiles\MyWordDoc.doc', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS Doc;

INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]  ( [file_type_id], [file],  [file_name], [filing_id], [created_at], [created_by], [is_confidential])
VALUES (@file_type_id, @Document, @file_name, @filing_id , @created_at, @created_by, @is_confidential);
```

*Edit: to address the comment from the OP* "How do I put another variable for file path." *the correct syntax of that would be to make use of the second parameter from `QUOTENAME` (note that this strongly assumes that `@filepath` can **never** have a length longer than 128 characters):*

```
SET @insertquery = N'DECLARE @Document AS VARBINARY(MAX);' + @CRLF +
                   N'SELECT @Document = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM OPENROWSET( BULK ' + QUOTENAME(@filepath,'''') + N', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS Doc;' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                   N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@databasename) + '.' +  QUOTENAME(@schemaname) + N'.' +  QUOTENAME(@tablename) + N'  ( [file_type_id], [file],  [file_name], [filing_id], [created_at], [created_by], [is_confidential])' + @CRLF + 
                   N'VALUES (@file_type_id, @Document, @file_name, @filing_id , @created_at, @created_by, @is_confidential);';
```

Comment: Wow somebody had their coffee today. Well done and fast like lightning!!!

Comment: It's much later in the day for me that yourself, @SeanLange . I've even been back from my lunch break for a couple of hours. :) Plus, I'm foolish enough to enjoy a dynamic SQL "challenge".

Comment: @Larnu . . . I am curious why you are manually inserting a `@CRLF` instead of just having a string span multiple lines -- which SQL Server supports.  Do you have a particular reason?  Or is this just the way that you write multiline strings?

Comment: I do, @GordonLinoff. [Why I define my Carriage Returns and Line Breaks as variables in Dynamic SQL](http://wp.larnu.uk/?p=49)

Comment: hahaha only about 6 hours later. I was about to post a very similar answer but saw yours. Between you and Gordon it is amazing I ever manage to get anything posted. :D

Comment: @Larnu: One more help..How do I put another variable for file path. Currently the file location `'C:\SampleTestFiles\MyWordDoc.doc'` is hardcoded and want to use `@filepath` variable. I did this: `FROM OPENROWSET( BULK '+QUOTENAME(@filepath)+', SINGLE_BLOB )` But it says Incorrect syntax near `'C:\SampleTestFiles\MyWordDoc.doc'`

Comment: @user2961127 , `@filepath` is defined as a `varchar(100)` so can I ***assume*** (and this is **very** important) that it's value will always be 100 characters or less?

Comment: @Larnu: Thanks for the help. Got to learn a lot about dynamic SQL today.

Comment: Glad to have helped, @user2961127 .